# Python - Convert Bracketed Number String to Integer Value

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.3

EDIT:
Solved by Haidro below.

Also thank you to everyone for helping out. Have been lurking here for a while after every google search, never realized how active this community is! Thanks again :).

---

I am trying to convert the following:

```
    ['(9,133,000)', '']
```

to just:

```
    -9133000
```

I have already tried using code such as:

```
mystring = [int(x) for x in mystring[0]]
```

but get an error: `invalid literal for int() with base 10 : '('`

How would I go about doing this? Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integers don't have commas in them. You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> L = ['(9,133,000)', '']
>>> print(-ast.literal_eval(L[0].replace(',','')))
-9133000
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python's builtin `translate` function for Strings.

```
a =  ['(9,133,000)', '']
intval = -int(a[0].translate(None, '(),'))
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_translate.htm

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me the following error:                 `<code>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    intval = -int(a[0].translate(None, '(),'))                 
TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)</code>

Comment: what's your python's version? I am using 2.7 and it works fine. maybe you can try maketrans as the described in the referred link.

Comment: @springrider He's using python 3.3 (note the tag)

Comment: Sorry I am having trouble with trying to put my errors in proper code format in comments. Also I am running the latest version, Python 3.3.